# Write a program that takes a character as input (string length 1) the output is the next character in the alphabet. If input is 'Z', output is 'A'

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, output, letter

Write a program that takes a character as input (a string of length 1), which you should assume is an upper-case character; the output should be the next character in the alphabet.

If the input is `'Z'`, your output should be `'A'`.

Here's what i've done so far but I’m not getting `A` when I input `Z`. I’m getting `[`.

Please help, what am I doing wrong?

```
input = (input()).upper()
for character in input:
   number = ord(character) + 1
   number1 = chr(number)
   if ord('z'):
       new_number = ord(character) - 25
        number2 = chr(new_number)

print(number1)
```

Comment: Dont call a variable `input` - it shadows the built in function

Comment: SO is no site for sharing your code and tasks. Do you have a question? [edit] and make clear what your problem is. [ask] and [tour] is a good place to start if you are new to this site.

Comment: `if ord('z'):`  is always true as ord("Z") != 0 so its truthy. You need to compare stuff. `if character == "Z": character = "A"` would be one way to do it.

Comment: Thank you so much! The exercise emphasised that we should use ASCII. Could you rewrite the code using ascii numbers. Sorry for all hassle

Answer (score 1):

A way of doing this may be via a `match` statement:

```
match (letter):
    case 'A':
        print('B')
    case 'B':
        print('C')
```

But you will need around 30 `case`s...

---

A better idea is to use a `list`:

```
letters = ['A', 'B', 'C'...]
```

then to get the letter

```
letter = input().upper()
```

and then to get the next element in the `list`:

```
print(letters[letters.find(letter)+1])
```

but there will be an error raised for `'Z'`, so you will need a `try`/`except` block for [`IndexError`](https://pythonprinciples.com/blog/index-errors/):

```
try:
    print(letters[letters.find(letter)+1])
except IndexError:
    print('A')
```

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out!! Thanks to everyone for reaching out with an alternative method! I'm ever grateful.

```
input = (input()).upper()
encrypted = ""
for character in input:
    if character == "":
        encrypted += ""
elif ord(character) + 1 > ord("Z"):
    encrypted += chr(ord(character) + 1 - 26)
else:
    encrypted += chr(ord(character) + 1)

print(encrypted)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a very simple answer:

```
myString = input()

name = ord(myString)

gor = name + 1

if name == 90:
   gor = 65
   

print(chr(gor))
```